# Skipping over items in the back stack when finishing an activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity that shows a list of items. When you tap on an item, it starts another activity to view the item's details. In the details activity, if you click the edit button, it starts a third activity to edit it.

In the edit activity's UI, I have a delete button. When the button is tapped and the item is deleted, I want to go back to the list of items, the first activity. But if I simply call `finish()` on the edit activity, it will go back to the details activity. This isn't right, because the item no longer exists - it was just deleted.

What is the best way to handle this? I could create an Intent and start a new instance of the list activity, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do. Is it possible to pop multiple items off of the back stack when finishing an activity?

Comment: The way I have done this in the past is to make the details activity editable.  Then, when you `finish()` that activity, return to the list and refresh the list of items to remove the newly deleted item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a contingency based off of the interaction in an `Activity` you are launching, you could use `startActivityForResult()` and `OnActivityResult()` in conjunction with `setResult()` on the `Activity` you need to know the results from.

You could then also finish your middle activity based on the result. Take a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: Nice, this worked for me. I had my edit activity return a result code indicating if the item was deleted, then in the details activity I checked the result code in `onActivityResult`, if it got the delete result code then it calls `finish()` which goes back one more to the list view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Easyest way to destroy current activity with cleaning task and relunch ListActivity;**

Delete button action:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(EditActivity.this,ListActivity.class);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(newIntent); 
finish();
```

**Or**
you can use setActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you've deleted the item -

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    YourActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(...); // Your list's Intent
i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); // Adds the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag
startActivity(i);
```

The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag keeps the new Activity from being added to the history stack.